# How do I interpret a URI string for a VS resource

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, embedded-resource

I have a file that I have made a Resource (Build Action = Resource) in a VS 2017 `WPF` project name `FlexReport`.

I used an example from a code snippet to get access to this resource:

```
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("FlexReport;component/Reports.flxr", UriKind.Relative));
```

I would like to find the reference that explains how to construct the string.

I assume that the first part of the string, "FlexReport" represents the name of the project (maybe incorrect assumption). And, the last part "/Reports.flxr" I recognize is the file name of the resource file.

**But, what about the "component"? Where did that come from? And, what other possibilities could this be?**

Is there a reference that explains how to build a Uri string?

Comment: It is called the [Pack URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf). Come back with more specific question after reading the article.

Comment: use this `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Reports.flxr", UriKind.Relative)` here Resources is your folder name

Answer (score 0):

A component is part of the [pack URI scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf) but the `Application.GetResourceStream` method does not accept pack URIs.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.getresourcestream?view=netframework-4.7.2) is pretty clear on this:

> The `Uri` that is passed to `GetResourceStream(Uri)` is either not relative, or is absolute but not in the `pack://application:,,,/` form.